# NodeJS Express Auth - Multiple database servers with multiple client databases

Tags: node.js, database, authentication

I'm working on a company "off-side, after hours" project that would allow users to request data from a client database via a NodeJS Rest API using oAuth2 (or maybe another token-based authentication system, whatever suits best).

The general Data structure would look like this:

```
- Node API Server (Handles the incoming requests)
--- oAuth 2 Users/Clients Database

- Database Server 1 (MySQL) (SRV1)
--- Client Database 1 (DBNAME1)
--- Client Database 2 (DBNAME2)
--- Client Database 3 (DBNAME3)
--- Client Database 4 (DBNAME4)

- Database Server 2 (MySQL) (SRV2)
--- Client Database 5 (DBNAME5)
--- Client Database 6 (DBNAME6)

- Database Server 3 (MySQL) (SRV3)
--- Client Database 7 (DBNAME7)
```

**Import notice**: A User will need to be able to be linked to multiple Client Databases.
(Preferably with the same user account, but a different Token (or maybe another identifier))

I want to have a clear goal about all this before I start coding everything and hit wall after wall during development.

The issue is. I currently have a working endpoint with a Client Database connection, but I can't seem to wrap my head arround it how to even get started with the implmentation.

The idea I had to store those identifiers:

```
- User 1
--- Name, Email, Pass, ..
--- Tokens/Connections:

------ Token: SRV1-{TokenHash}
------ Database: DBNAME2
------ Scope: *

------ Token: SRV3-{TokenHash}
------ Database: DBNAME7
------ Scope: *
```

The API endpoint would look like this:

```
api.domain.com:3000/v1/CustomerService/customers
```

The User would authenticate via the Request Headers.

The Application would then get the Client Database name from the token link and the Server from the first 4 characters of the Token itself.

And would, for example, result into:

```
GET data from: Database Server 3 (SRV3) -> Client Database 7 (DBNAME7) -> Table:Customers
```

I've looked at the whole oAuth2 and JWT implementations, but everything is designed for like 1 dataset with multiple users.

Are there more efficient or better ways to handle the above situation? Should I step away from the whole token-based authentication?

I can't seem to find any information about this or how other API's handle this.

Comment: Are the servers all registered under one or many domains?

Comment: @RossBush They all have their own domain like srv1.company.com, srv2.company.com,.. and finally the api.company.com. So I would use a connection config with an array of servers with every credential for every server etc.